# Не подцепляется юзернейм в ForeignKey

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, backend

Есть форма, на которой пользователь загружает фото, после чего создается объект Photo, где поле img- сама картинка, поле usr- username залогиненного в данный момент User. При субмите все проходит успешно, создается Photo object, но usr не подцепляет username пользователя, загрузившего фото. В чем дело?

```
class UploadFormView(View):
    form_class = UploadForm
    template_name = 'upload_form.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            photo = form.save(commit=False)
            img = form.cleaned_data['img']
            usr = request.user.username
            photo.save()
            return redirect('regindex:index')
```

models.py:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField()
    usr = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Вам нужно указать `self.request`, т.к. вы работаете с классом.
2. Не нужно указывать `username`.

Вот исправленная строчка:

```
usr = self.request.user
```

**[UPDATE]**

```
# views.py
class UploadFormView(View):
    form_class = UploadForm
    template_name = 'upload_form.html'

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(self.request, self.template_name, {'form':form})

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            photo = form.save(commit=False)
            photo.img = form.cleaned_data['img']
            photo.usr = self.request.user
            photo.save()
            return redirect('regindex:index')


# models.py - без изменений
class Photo(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField()
    usr = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

И если вы используете метод `.save()` - ваша форма должна быть модельная (т.е. `ModelForm`)

```
class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        # fields = ('img', )
        exclude = ('usr',)
```

Comment: Не помогло. Все так же не цепляется

Comment: В вашей функции сделайте изменения: вместо `def post(self, request):` напишите так `post(self, *args, **kwargs):`  и в `form = self.form_class(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)`

Comment: Опять ничего :(

Comment: @Дмитрий, Уже интереснее) Какая ошибка, что пишет?

Comment: В этом-то и дело, что ничего не пишет. Объект создается успешно, но если зайти в админку и посмотреть свойства, в графе usr стоит прочерк. Дома буду, попробую сделать то, что вы предложили в дополнении к ответу, спасибо!